# SQL Server : to get Max date value

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data in the table:

[image]

I have tried using the below query to get the latest `CMBR_MBST` with its respective `CMBR_CCMP`

```
SELECT CMBR_CCMP, MAX(CMBR_MBST) AS CMBR_MBST
FROM CMBR 
GROUP BY CMBR_CCMP
```

[image]

The result is close to what I need. I just need the extra 2 columns, `CMBR_MMBR` & `CMBR_MBED` to be displayed.

For example:

[image]

Can someone please help me with the query? Your help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT TOP 1 with ties *
FROM CMBR 
Order by row_number()over(parition by CMBR_CCMP order by CMBR_MBST desc)
```

Another way (commonly used technique)

```
select * from
(
SELECT *,row_number()over(parition by CMBR_CCMP order by CMBR_MBST desc) Rn
FROM CMBR
) A
Where Rn =1
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :D Thanks alot!